# Secret volumes do not work on multinode docker setup

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup a multinode kubernetes 1.0.3 cluster using instructions from https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.md.

I create a secret volume using the following spec in `myns` namespace:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: myns
  labels:
    name: mysecret
data:
  myvar: "bUNqVlhCVjZqWlZuOVJDS3NIWkZHQmNWbXBRZDhsOXMK"`

Create secret volume:

`$ kubectl create -f mysecret.yml --namespace=myns`

Check to see if secret volume exists:

`$ kubectl get secrets --namespace=myns

NAME       TYPE      DATA
mysecret   Opaque    1`

Here is the Pod spec of the consumer of the secret volume:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: myns
spec:
  containers:
    - image: busybox
      command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
      name: busybox
      volumeMounts:
        - name: mysecret
          mountPath: /etc/mysecret
          readOnly: true
  volumes:
    - name: mysecret
      secret:
        secretName: mysecret`

Create the Pod

`kubectl create -f busybox.yml --namespace=myns`

Now if I exec into the docker container to inspect the contents of the `/etc/mysecret` directory. I find it to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

What namespace are your pod and secret in?  They must be in the same namespace.  Would you post a gist or pastebin of the Kubelet log?  That contains information that can help us diagnose this.

Also, are you running the Kubelet on your host directly or in a container?

Comment: updated the question to have the namespace details. Regarding the setup, I am using the [Docker Multinode](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.md) instructions from the Getting started guides to setup the cluster on VM's running ubuntu 12.04 to setup a two node cluster. I have no idea where to look for the logs. Can you direct me.